# Rails 4 application all requests are being called twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every request on my rails 4 app is being called twice, so I removed all java scripts and but that didn't work. Please see the below result code time within 5 millisecond two calls.

Development and production env both are getting same result.

Result One:

```
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-16 20:45:51 +0530
Processing by PagesController#landing as HTML ....

Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-16 20:45:55 +0530
Processing by PagesController#landing as HTML ....
```

Result two:

```
Started GET "/haggles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-16 21:06:51 +0530
Processing by HagglesController#new as HTML....

Started GET "/haggles/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-16 21:06:53 +0530
Processing by HagglesController#new as HTML...
```

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, does the same thing happen when you `curl`?

Comment: All browsers same result.  ajax calling is working

Comment: I checked curl it working, No twice call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the different timestamps, I think we can rule out duplicate logging and treat it as duplicate requests. The only time I've seen something like that happen is when you have something along the lines of

```
<img src="#" alt="">
```

within your view. Since you're seeing this in multiple views, it may be within your layout.

Comment: Thank you , your solotion is worked,  My layout had 
<img id="leftBanner" alt="Left banner" src="#">,  I remove this tag now working